# InstagramKit receivedValidAccessTokenFromURL doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to use Shyambhat's InstagramKit (from the DEV branch) and I just can't get the `receivedValidAccessTokenFromURL` method working.

Currently I'm working with swift 3.0 the code looks as follows (for testing purposes)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        engine = InstagramEngine.shared();
        let iScope: InstagramKitLoginScope = [.comments, .followerList, .likes, .relationships];

        let iAuthURL = engine.authorizationURL(for: iScope);

        loginWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: iAuthURL));
        loginWebView.delegate = self;
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        let url = request.url;
        try! engine.receivedValidAccessToken(from: url!)

        return true;
    }
```

I've set the following in my info.plist

> InstagramAppClientId:             'myid'
>
> InstagramAppRedirectURL:     'http://example.com'

For some reason instagram doesn't allow the redirect url to be app:// anymore.
When I put a debug on the request.url. This shows me the following

`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=myid&redirect_uri=http%3A//example.com&response_type=token&scope=comments%20relationships%20likes%20follower_list`

I'm hoping someone here has experience with this library and can help me out.

Comment: Do you need to redirect to another app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out. What I did is the following.

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        do {
            if let url = request.url {
                if (String(describing: url).range(of: "access") != nil){
                    try engine.receivedValidAccessToken(from: url)

                if let accessToken = engine.accessToken {
                    NSLog("accessToken: \(accessToken)")
                }
                }
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
        return true
    }
```

I check if the url contains the access token if it does then I'll let the engine actually get the access token. The error occurred because it was trying to get the access token while it wasn't available when you open the app up the first time.

Answer (score 1):

InstagramKit Swift 3.0 get access token:

> Info.plist (added)

```
<key>InstagramAppClientId</key>
<string>3ewqrewr23453243244qwrqwefwefgw42</string>
<key>InstagramAppRedirectURL</key>
<string>https://www.instagram.com/</string>
```

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import InstagramKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   // deleteChache()
    initWebView()
}
func deleteChache() {
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
        for cookie in cookies {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
}

}

// MARK: UIWebView

extension ViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {

func initWebView() {

    webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    webView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(webView)
    authorizationRequestInWebView()
}

func authorizationRequestInWebView() {


    let url = InstagramEngine.shared().authorizationURL()
    let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    do {
        if let url = request.url {
            try InstagramEngine.shared().receivedValidAccessToken(from: url)

            if let accessToken = InstagramEngine.shared().accessToken {
                NSLog("accessToken: \(accessToken)")
            }
        }
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
    return true
}
}
```

### Console result

Comment: it gives me the following error when trying to call the `receivedValidAccessToken` command

`Error Domain=Foundation._GenericObjCError Code=0 "(null)"`

Comment: Same. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your problem. This code doesn't work?

Comment: I get Error Domain=Foundation._GenericObjCError Code=0 "(null)"

Comment: I checked the URL and the access token is there... But the receivedValidAccessToken function fails.